# Converting date string in unknown format to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm building a generic custom `strToDatetime(string)` function. The date string may be in some different formats. The 2 most popular alternatives seem `datetime.strptime(string, format)` and `dateutil.parser(string)`. It seems `datetime.strptime()` requires a format and `dateutil.parser()` does not, so the possible solutions seem to be:

1. Test date strings pattern to find date string format and use `datetime.strptime()`
2. Use `dateutil.parser()`

Is this correct? Alternative 1 (harder and may require maintenance in the future) has advantages, such as performance?

Comment: I won't worry about performance *right now*. Simple guideline: 1. Make it work, 2. Wake it right, 3. Make it fast. Alternatively: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I would always go with the simplest (`dateutil.parser`), someone has always done the work for you and it's less likely to spit out an error at a malformed (according to your `format`) date. Performance difference is likely to be small (but the only way to know is to test!)

Comment: Agree with @hayden. It's also much easier to test. If you attempt to parse against a set of known formats until it succeeds, you know exactly where you are at, you are using proven code. Where as testing to see which parser you should use leaves you with a huge set of test cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `parse()` method of dateutil is very flexible and will parse almost anything you throw at it.

However, because of that flexibility, if your input is limited to a certain number of patterns, custom code that checks for those patterns then uses `datetime.datetime.strptime()` could easily beat it.

Since this depends entirely on the number of patterns you need to test for, the only thing you can do is *measure* which one will be faster *for your specific usecases*.

Answer (score 1):

I would always go with the simplest (dateutil.parser), someone has always done the work for you and it's less likely to spit out an error at a malformed (according to your format) date.

Of course, **sometimes you will want it to throw an error at a malformed, perhaps ambiguous date**, and in this case you should use `strptime`!

#### Performance test:

I called `parse(d)` and `datetime.datetime.strptime(d, f)` each 100,000 times.

```
parse(d) took 5.62201309204 seconds
datetime.datetime.strptime(d, f) took 1.78140687943 seconds
    (where d = '11-02-1980' and f = '%m-%d-%Y')
```

*It seems that if you know the precise date format then `strptime` is around 3 times faster, granted this is not a very scientific experiment but I think it gives a good indication.*

So is this slight speed improvement worth the additional unnecessary complication/headache? That's up to you (but probably not).