# Python convert date string from an UNKNOWN format

Tags: python-3.x, date, format

Noob here - sorry in advance. I have a large data set with dates in a variety of unknown formats. I need to convert those unknown date formats into a consistent format such as "M/D/YYYY".

All the samples I see require that you know the input format, which I do not. I found references to "dateutil" which may work, but I cannot find out how to add that to my WINDOWS environment. All I've seen is "use PIP" which is Greek to me and WINDOWS apparently.

1. Is there a function (DEF) out there that takes a date string in an unknown format and converts it to a date object that can be re-formatted consistently?

   - OR -
2. If dateutil will help me solve my problem is there a WINDOWS version and how do I install it and then reference it?

Please do not refer me to the following, it does not answer my question: [Converting date string in unknown format to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723746/converting-date-string-in-unknown-format-to-datetime)

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: PIP is a python package tool.  You use it to install packages, such as `dateutils`.  Type `pip search dateutils` to see the available packages.  If it says it's an unknown command, try changing directory to your Python install directory first.

Comment: Thank you. Once I figured out how to run PIP then added admin privileges it worked! "python3 -m pip install python-dateutil"